# No sound on Genymotion 2.8 emulator

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, android, genymotion

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

I have installed genymotion-2.8.0-linux_x64 on my Ubuntu 16.04, with virtualbox version 5.1.8. when launching the emulator, there is no voice at all. I tried to change android version or the device type with no luck. Can anyone give a hint, where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It might be problem with VirtualBox configuration. If so, changing the "Host Audio Driver" to "Pulseaudio" may fix it.

Check the answer at [**Genymotion android emulator sound problem**](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=186890) on the [Linux Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/index.php). As [Jamkirk](https://forums.linuxmint.com/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=160333&sid=9af33798500e0aa9e6821299a0f75172) wrote in [this post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=186890#p981482):

> I have the exact same setup as you and fixed this by going in to the
>   Oracle VM Virtualbox settings for the VM that Genymotion creates. Go
>   to Settings -> Audio -> Host Audio Driver and change it to PulseAudio.
>
> It still crackles sometimes but its a big improvement